# Creating grid editor in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm making app which will provide possibility to input elements to database. Creating form for creating 1 element it easy but for putting to database many at once isn't.

I'm asking if there is some way to create something like winForms's datagridView in asp.mvc5

or it's need to be done using JS framework like knockout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MVC then why don't you use Grid using Jquery

try this http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Comment: Looks nice but it doesn't meet my needs. Add row functionality only gives possibility to add one row at once. I need to eg. add at once 30  elements which differs only in their serial number etc.

Answer (score 1):

ok then use ajax in jquery

send a json full with data

var mydatamap={"serial":"serial1", "name":,"Person1" ...........  }

and populate your grid with that type of data

Comment: Ok I think I was unclear with my question. I need to populate database from grid.. Not grid from database.

Comment: http://mudassarkhan.wordpress.com/2009/01/10/accessing-xml-files-using-adonet/  try this, you just need to create XML file from your grid, you can use jquery for traversing each tr td and send the xml string into a generic handler which will perform insert/update/delete